# output via echo for an input value

Tags: php, mysql, html, input

```
<input type="text" name="prod_id" value="<?php echo $product['table']['id']; ?>" />
```

But it doesn't show up anything although the $product variable is sure to have been properly initialized, what might be the problem ?

Here is the print_r produce

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [product_table] => Array ( 
            [id] => 5 
            [quantity] => 20 
            [name] => something 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: The only problem would be `$product['table']['id']` is empty. `var_dump` it and see what it returns.

Comment: CrystalBall.exe has stopped working. Either: a) that variable is misinitialized OR b) it *is* properly initialized to an empty value. Show us more code.

Comment: first use this to see what is in product print_r($product)

Comment: Thanks I repeat It does have values, the textbox contains empty string

Comment: May be $product variable is defined but what about 'table' and 'id'.. Have you initialized proper array key and values... Why don't you post here what print_r($product); is having..

Answer (score 5):

You have to access the variable as `$product[0]['product_table']['id']` and not `$product['table']['id']`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to output contents of a non-existing key. You have 'product_table', not 'table'.

Edit:

And it also needs to be `$product[0]['product_table']['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="prod_id" value="<?php echo $product[0]['product_table']['id']; ?>" />
```

Please add index [0] to ensure that if the provided array have multiple values then only first one will be picked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
extract($product[0]);
<input type="text" name="prod_id" value="<?php echo $product_table['id']; ?>" />
```